# pgfgantt: Straight line to top middle of milestone

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

Is there a way to get a straight line to a milestone in pgfgantt?

If the end of the preceding ganttbar is on the same date as the milestone, a line from the tail to the start looks strange:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
  \begin{ganttchart}{1}{4}
    \ganttbar[name=e1]{My bar}{2}{3}\\
    \ganttmilestone[name=e2]{My milestone}{3}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-s]{e1}{e2}
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would be a solution without the package ```pgfgantt``` ok, too?

Comment: @current_user I do not think that it is necessary to redo the diagram in Ti*k*Z. You could simply define a new link style with `\newgantlinktype`, and the syntax is Ti*k*Z. Of course, it would be helpful to know what the OP wants.

Comment: You could just replace `\ganttlink[link type=f-s]{e1}{e2}` by `\draw[-latex] (e1.south east) -- (e2.north)
 node[midway,right]{\emph{finish-start}};`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a new link type as proposed by marmot (see page 45 of the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfgantt/pgfgantt.pdf) [version 5.0]), like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\newganttlinktype{f-m}{
 \ganttsetstartanchor{on right=1}
 \ganttsetendanchor{on left=0}
 \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
  ([xshift=-.2pt]\xLeft, \yUpper) --       % xshift to fit arrow
  node[pos=.5, /pgfgantt/link label node] {\ganttlinklabel} 
  (\xRight, \yLower);
}
\setganttlinklabel{f-m}{a fancy link}

\begin{document}
  \begin{ganttchart}{1}{4}
    \ganttbar[name=e1]{My bar}{2}{3}\\
    \ganttmilestone[name=e2]{My milestone}{3}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-m]{e1}{e2}
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Which would result in:

[image]

Or without label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\newganttlinktype{f-m}{
 \ganttsetstartanchor{on right=1}
 \ganttsetendanchor{on left=0}
 \draw[/pgfgantt/link]
  ([xshift=-.2pt]\xLeft, \yUpper) -- 
  (\xRight, \yLower);
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{ganttchart}{1}{4}
    \ganttbar[name=e1]{My bar}{2}{3}\\
    \ganttmilestone[name=e2]{My milestone}{3}
    \ganttlink[link type=f-m]{e1}{e2}
  \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution, which makes nice use of pgfgantts synatex for creating new links.

Answer (score 3):

So, this is just a proposal.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,every node/.style={font=\sf}]
        \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
        \draw (.5,2) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
            \fill[xshift=2.5cm,yshift=.5cm,black,rotate=45] (0,0) rectangle (.4,.4);
        \node[left] at (0,2.5) {My bar};
        \node[left] at (0,.5) {My milestone};
            \draw[red,->] (2.5,2) -- (2.5,1.1) node[fill=white,midway,right] {\tiny finish-to-start};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could just take the OP's code and add your Ti*k*Z command, something like `\draw[red,->] (e1.south east) -- (e2.north) node[fill=white,midway,right] {\emph{finish-to-start}};`. And please add a screen shot of the result such that other people upvote you. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and even more for the helpful comment. It is of course nice to have such a short workaround.